# Use Xuggler with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, xuggler

is there a way to use Xuggler with JavaFX? Or can I use JavaFX Media Player to manipulate and after that save the manipulated video to the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xuggler with JavaFX. There are no dependencies between them. Just extract the frames and encode them.